# Can a familiar impede an opponent in some way?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, familiars

I know a familiar from the [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell can take the Help action which provides advantage.

Is there any way for the familiar to use its action to impede an enemy in order to make their attacks be at a disadvantage? Preferably without the familiar attacking.

Answer (score 11):

### No.

The [Help action](https://5thsrd.org/combat/actions_in_combat/#help) only provides the ability to grant advantage to an attack.

The only way that a familiar could impose disadvantage on a creature's attack is if it has an ability or attack that explicitly has that effect.

Answer (score 10):

## Not without attacking

There is no stock inverse-of-help action.  However, a caster with pact of the chain warlock class feature (Player's Handbook p.107), can have a pseudodragon that does have an attack can result in the target rolling attacks and abilities at disadvantage.

### Pseudodragon Sting

A [pseudodragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pseudodragon)'s poison sting inflicts the [poisoned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Poisoned) condition, which causes disadvantage.

### Harder getting in the way

Familiars are usually tiny.  Tiny creatures only take up a [quarter of the space of a medium or small creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#CreatureSize).  That makes it more difficult to get in the way over other creatures.

### Being a target

Whenever a familiar is making itself a nuisance or threat in combat, it increases the risk of it being attacked.  So by getting in the way, attacking, or otherwise participating in combat is likely to get it swatted or deliberately included in the enemies area effects.

Comment: I would definitely mention that this is _only valid_ for a pact of the chain warlock. No other classes can summon a Pseudodragon as a familiar and, even if they could, without the Pact of the Chain feature Familiars cannot attack.